# Visualize SQL-query as bar chart Apache superset

Tags: sql, postgresql, apache-superset

I have created a query which corresponds to exactly what I want to visualize, however I am stuck on how to sort this in apache superset as bar chart.

```
SELECT
  'Car' AS "Mode of transport",
  SUM(CASE WHEN "Q9_1" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Count yes",
  SUM(CASE WHEN "Q9_1" = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Count no"
FROM public.testdatat
WHERE "Q9_1" IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT
  'Bicycle' AS "Mode of transport",
  SUM(CASE WHEN "Q9_2" = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Count yes",
  SUM(CASE WHEN "Q9_2" = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Count no"
FROM public.testdatat
WHERE "Q9_2" IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY "My column" DESC
LIMIT 10000;
```

I am not sure how to use "UNION ALL" as a break between selects. And if i put the mode of transports as Metrics or X-axis and put all 4 SUM-statements as Dimensions it will display them all stacked for each mode of transport, but i only want the Yes/No for each Q9_1 or Q9_2 for each mode of transport.

I do not wish to create a separata dataset, i want to use my original one, to be able to use Cross-filtering.